# Derive session duration when only timestamp is available in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to calculate the session duration for the usage of an app. However, in the provided log, the only relevant information I can obtain is timestamp. Below is a simplified log for a single user.

```
record_num, user_id, record_ts
-----------------------------
1, uid_1, 12:01am
2, uid_1, 12:02am
3, uid_1, 12:03am
4, uid_1, 12:22am
5, uid_1, 12:22am
6, uid_1, 12:25am
```

Assuming a session is concluded after 15 minutes of inactivity, the above log would consist 2 sessions. And now I would like to calculate the average duration for the two sessions.

I can derive the number of sessions by first calculate the time differences between each record, and whenever a difference exceeds 15 minutes, a session is counted.

But to derive the duration as I would need to know the min(record_ts) and max(record_ts) for each session. However, without a session_id of some sort, I could not group the records into associated sessions.

Is there any SQL based approach where I can solve this?

Comment: This is a gaps and islands problem, and you'll need a BigQuery guru to give you an answer (I don't know how).  By the way, is there a `user_id` column in your table?  If there is, then add that to the sample table in your question, as it should be part of the query.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Tim. I've revised the sample as suggested.

Comment: If it is an app you're developing (which I don't know because you didn't mention it), then you could add a table tracking logon, logoff, auto logoff due to inactivity. And you could add the inactivity time as a config parameter. Then you log the logon, logoff and auto logoff time and you can easily derive the session time from it for a given uid (provided the session lasted longer than the inactivity time specifies because the user wasn't away from his PC).

Comment: Hello Matt. Thanks for the suggestion. I have already talked to the developers on implementing solutions for future data. However, for the sake of intellectual curiosity, I would still like to explore the possibility of deriving the durations using existing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the date too (without it would mean calculating whether the end time of the session began before the start time), something like this would work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 1 record_num, "uid_1" user_id, TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01 12:01:00') record_ts)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2 record_num, "uid_1" user_id, TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01 12:02:00') record_ts)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 3 record_num, "uid_1" user_id, TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01 12:03:00') record_ts)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 4 record_num, "uid_1" user_id, TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01 12:22:00') record_ts)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 5 record_num, "uid_1" user_id, TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01 12:22:00') record_ts)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 6 record_num, "uid_1" user_id, TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01 12:25:00') record_ts)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 7 record_num, "uid_1" user_id, TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01 12:59:00') record_ts)),

sessions as
(SELECT
  if(timestamp_diff(record_ts,lag(record_ts,1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY     
    record_ts, record_num),MINUTE) >= 15 OR
    lag(record_ts,1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY record_ts, record_num) IS NULL,1,0)
  session, record_num, user_id, record_ts
FROM CTE)

SELECT sum(session) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY record_ts, record_num) 
  sessionNo, record_num, user_id, record_ts
FROM sessions
```

The key being the number of minutes you want between sessions. In the case above I've put it at 15 minutes (>= 15). Obviously it might be useful to concatenate the session number with the user_Id and a session start time to create a unique session identifer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Bobby. This is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to solve the problem by following and expanding on your codes. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in the following steps:

- Use `lag()` and some logic to determine when a session begins.
- Use cumulative sum to assign sessions.
- Then aggregation to get averages.

So, to get information on each session:

```
select user_id, session, min(record_ts), max(record_ts),
       timestamp_diff(max(record_ts), min(record_ts), second) as dur_seconds
from (select l.*,
             countif( record_ts > timestamp_add(prev_record_ts, interval 15 minute) ) as session
      from (select l.*,
                   lag(record_ts, 1, record_ts) over (partition by user_id order by record_ts) as prev_record_ts
            from log l
           ) l
group by record_num, user_id;
```

The average is one further step:

```
with s as (
      select user_id, session, min(record_ts), max(record_ts),
             timestamp_diff(max(record_ts), min(record_ts), second) as dur_seconds
      from (select l.*,
                   countif( record_ts > timestamp_add(prev_record_ts, interval 15 minute) ) as session
            from (select l.*,
                         lag(record_ts, 1, record_ts) over (partition by user_id order by record_ts) as prev_record_ts
                  from log l
                 ) l
      group by record_num, user_id
     )
select user_id, avg(dur_seconds)
from s
group b user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Gordon. The resulted outputs were a bit wonky, but I understood the general concept of your approach, and think I could make it work by doing more tinkering. I appreciate the help!